# Three normals of a hyperbola passing through the same point on the curve

Tags: geometry, plane-geometry

The normals at three points $P$, $Q$, $R$ on a rectangular hyperbola $xy = c^2$ intersect at a point on the curve. Prove that the centre of the hyperbola is the centroid of the triangle $PQR$.

I copied the the question word by word. Let assume that the points are (c$ t_1$,$\frac{c}{ t_1}$) , (c$ t_2$,$\frac{c}{ t_2}$) & (c$ t_3$,$\frac{c}{t_3}$), even if I draw the normal, at all the three point how do I intersect three lines at one point.
[image: Question]

Comment: In general, these normals do not intersect in a single point ; it will occur only for a very particular relationship between $t_1, t_2, t_3$ (say for example $t_1+t_2+t_3=0$).

Comment: Thank you for the image, but which book is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Points $P$, $Q$, $R$ cannot exist as stated. At least two among them must lie on the same branch of the given hyperbola, so we may assume for instance that $P$ and $Q$ are given by
$$
P=(x_1,c^2/x_1),\quad
Q=(x_2,c^2/x_2),\quad
\hbox{with $x_1>0$ and $x_2>0$}.
$$
The intersection point of the normals at $P$ and $Q$ is
$$
N=\left(\frac{c^4+{x_1}^3 {x_2}+{x_1}^2 {x_2}^2+{x_1} {x_2}^3}
{{x_1}{x_2}(x_1+x_2)},
\frac{c^4 {x_1}^2+c^4 {x_1}{x_2}+c^4 {x_2}^2+{x_1}^3{x_2}^3}
{c^2 {x_1} {x_2}(x_1+x_2)}\right)
$$
and 
$$
x_Ny_N=
\frac{\left(c^4 \left({x_1}^2+{x_1}
   {x_2}+{x_2}^2\right)+{x_1}^3 {x_2}^3\right)
   \left(c^4+{x_1} {x_2} \left({x_1}^2+{x_1}
   {x_2}+{x_2}^2\right)\right)}{c^2 {x_1}^2 {x_2}^2
   ({x_1}+{x_2})^2}.
$$
If $x_1$ and $x_2$ are both positive, the above expression attains its minimum $4c^2$ for $x_1=x_2=c$. It follows that $x_Ny_N>c^2$ and $N$ doesn't lie on the hyperbola.

It is then impossible that three normals at different points on the hyperbola meet at the same point on the hyperbola.

Comment: I worked little more and solved it, let the general coordinate be (ct, c/t) , make a normal equation, put a common point (ct',c/t') for (x,y),   in the normal equation after factorization, we get one cubic equation, the coefficient of sum is zero so also the coefficient of product of two number, that is what i require

Comment: As you say you solved it, would you please tell me just one example of three points $P$, $Q$, $R$ as described in your question? I suspect at least one among them will have complex coordinates.

Comment: we get the folliwing equation (t'-t)($t^3$+$ \frac{1}{t'}$)=0

Comment: We only want to prove that centriod of triangle PQR is origin and not the coordinate P,Q&R

Comment: I understand that, but unfortunately points $P$, $Q$ and $R$ cannot exist as stated, The problem is flawed, not your "solution".

Comment: Unless, of course, complex points are allowed. But that should be told in the question. May I ask where is that problem taken from?

Comment: I agree but the framer of the question want only to find centriod of triangle , i only post question when I struggle while solving, i have seen wrong question but one can derieve the answer

Comment: Let me upload the problem in image

Comment: The parametric points are (ct,$ \frac{c}{t}$)

Comment: I edited a bit my answer, adding some details.

Answer (score 3):

A triangle with vertices on the hyperbola cannot have the origin as centroid

*proof*

Let $y=\dfrac{c^2}{x}$ be the equation of the hyperbola and $A\left(a,\dfrac{c^2}{a}\right);\;B\left(b,\dfrac{c^2}{b}\right)$ two points on the hyperbola

The third vertex $C$ has coordinates $C\left(x,\dfrac{c^2}{x}\right)$

The relation $a+b+x=0\to x=-a-b$ must held in order to have origin $O(0,0)$ centroid of the triangle $ABC$. Therefore the point $C$ has actual coordinates $C\left(-a-b,\dfrac{c^2}{-a-b}\right)$

Consider now the $y-$coordinates of the vertices of the triangle $ABC$

They must satisfy the relation $\dfrac{y_A+y_B+y_C}{3}=0$ that is $y_A+y_B+y_C=0$

$\dfrac{c^2}{a}+\dfrac{c^2}{b}+\dfrac{c^2}{-a-b}=\dfrac{c^2 \left(a^2+a b+b^2\right)}{a b (a+b)}$

$a^2+ab+b^2\ne 0$ for any  $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$ and this concludes the proof.

*remark*

As no triangle having vertices on the hyperbola can have centroid in the origin to a greater extent the proposition in the Original Post is false since triangle $PQR$ cannot exist

Comment: I totally agree with you , logically it is not possible but the framer of this question wants to test mathematical skills on rectangular parabola.

Answer (score 1):

Let normal to the hyperbola at $(ct,\frac{c}{ t})$ is 
$t^{2}x-t^{3}c=y- \frac{c}{t}$

Let the common point where all the normal intersect is $(ct',\frac{c}{ t'})$

Plugging this in the equation we get the form as

$(t^{3} + \frac{1}{ t'})(t'-t)=0$

$t^{3} + \frac{1}{ t'}=0$

Coefficient of $t^2 =0$ & coefficient of $t =0$ viz.

$ \ t_1+ \ t_2+ \ t_3 =0$

&

$ \ t_1\ t_2+ \ t_2\ t_3+ \ t_1\ t_3 =0$.

Hence centriod lies on origin.

Comment: Your proof would be OK if those points existed. But - as the other two answers show - they do not. Of course you did exactly what the author of the exercise wanted you to do, but nonetheless this exercise, as stated, is wrong.