# Normal Rectangular Hyperbola-Extension

Tags: geometry

[image: Hyp]

I have already posted this question , although I have solved it , but during discussion , i was asked whether such type of hyperbola exist. 
Now my question is normal to the hyperbola $xy=c^2$ is drawn from point P,Q and R which meets on point S which lies on $xy=c^2$ .Does this type of Hyperbola exist.

Please refer to the following Question [Normal(Rectangular Hyperbola)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2409466/normalrectangular-hyperbola/2409696?noredirect=1#comment4974732_2409696)

Comment: @Aretino I have posted this question for discussion

Comment: I think I already gave you the answer at the linked question. What is not clear in my answer there?

Comment: Instead of asking a new question, you should edit your old question or ask there for explanations.

Comment: @Aretino I thought of adding it but i thought against it because in the question it was asked to prove that centroid lies on triangle, but it was discussed whether such type of triangle exist so i thought of adding another question so as not to intermingle with the original question.